# Change Exim file with WHM Cpanel

Tags: email, pipe, edit, whm, exim

Hi i started using osTicket for my helpdesk and i was able to do the Email pipe successfully, but even if the ticket is created, the user receives: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender.

In osTicket it says to change de exim document, but i have WHM and i don't know how to change it.
Can someone tell me how to change the following using the WHM editor

```
 driver = pipe
 return_output

 driver = pipe
 group = "${lookup{$domain}lsearch* {/etc/userdomains}{$value}}"
 return_output
 user = "${lookup{$domain}lsearch* {/etc/userdomains}{$value}}"
```

i need to change the **return_output** to **return_fail_output**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to change your EXIM config file.  In WHM, you can go to: **Service Configuration -> Exim Configuration** and click on '**Advanced Editor**' (at the bottom) to have access to it.

I will warn to be careful in there as it may cause issues, but that's where it looks like you'll want to put your rules and such.